# Python Pylab linspace import order question?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use Pylab to plot the function sin(x)/|x|, but I am facing with this problem.

When I run this code, it worked fine.

```
from pylab import *
from math import *
from numpy import *

x=linspace(-10*pi,10*pi,10000)
plot(x,sin(x)/abs(x))
show()
```

However, this occurs an error. **TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from math import *

x=linspace(-10*pi,10*pi,10000)
plot(x,sin(x)/abs(x))
show()
```

The only difference is the import order between 'numpy' and 'math'

I don't know why its matter?

Comment: Probably you overwrite numpy with math functions. Be careful if you import in this way.

Comment: Can you describe more detail ? I am new to python, not farmiliar with each library.

Comment: `a = 1; a = 2` vs `a = 2; a = 1` or `from numpy import sin` vs `from math import sin`

Comment: Both `numpy` and `math` define `sin`. Which one do you want? The solution is: Don't do `from some_module import *`. If two libraries have a function of the same name then the later import will overwrite the earlier one. Instead do `import some_module` and prefix every call to a function with `some_module`, as for example `math.sin()` (which is apparently the one you want). When you are not familiar with a library, doing `from ... import *` means that you don't know what you are importing. That is why the advice is not to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the way the libraries are called might be overwritten, it is always best to cut it simple and short like this so that the program do not get confused:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(-10*np.pi,10*np.pi,10000)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x)/abs(x))
plt.show()
```

You will get this:

[image]